# Nhibernate property not found exception when returning a list of ints using AliasToBeanResultTransformer

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am getting a strange error when trying to return a list of integers from a raw query using the `AliasToBeanResultTransformer`.  Here is the code *(`PersonId` is an `char(9)`)*:

```
nHibernateService
    .CurrentSession
    .CreateSQLQuery(
                @"
                select PersonId
                from Person")
    .SetResultTransformer(new NHibernate.Transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(int)))
    .List<int>();
```

The error is:

> NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property 'PersonId' in class 'System.Int32'
>         at NHibernate.Properties.ChainedPropertyAccessor.GetSetter(Type theClass, String propertyName)
>         at NHibernate.Transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer.TransformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases)
>         at NHibernate.Loader.Custom.CustomLoader.GetResultList(IList results, IResultTransformer resultTransformer)
>         at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.ListCustomQuery(ICustomQuery customQuery, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results)
>         at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(NativeSQLQuerySpecification spec, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results)
>         at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List[T](NativeSQLQuerySpecification spec, QueryParameters queryParameters)

We are using a result transformer because the database type ID is a char(9), but PersonId is an Int32 in code. Is there a way to get this working without changing the schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case we won't need `IResultTransformer`. This should be enough:

```
nHibernateService
    .CurrentSession
    .CreateSQLQuery(" select PersonId from Person")
    .List<int>();
```

Result transformers are useful, when converting columns (with alias) into DTO objects. In this case, single `ValueType` is returned, no need to transform.

In case, that the DB (e.g. SQL Server) has the value PersonId stored as `varchar`, we can simply convert with a CAST function

```
nHibernateService
    .CurrentSession
    .CreateSQLQuery(@" select CAST(PersonId as int)
          from Person")
    .List<int>();
```

Comment: I provided more information about the error.  Basically the field in the database is a char(9) but in our code it is an Int32 property.  If we remove the result transformer, we get the following error: System.ArgumentException: The value "648880508" is not of type "System.Int32" and cannot be used in this generic collection.

Comment: Awesome, thanks that worked. Although I am very curious.  The previous code has been working up until now... I would still like to know what may have changed that would cause it to stop working.

Comment: Great if that helped! ;) *honestly I would be surprised if the transformer was working with ValueType. It really need properties of object, and map them to aliases of returned columns...* But, good that it is working right now ;) Enjoy NHibernate